# Why do I have to open Serial Monitor to display what is in loop function?

Tags: serial, esp8266, lcd, code-review, nodemcu

Why do I have to open Serial Monitor to display non-NaN values retrieved from DHT22,
what am I doing wrong in the code below?

```c
#include <DHT.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
// OLED display TWI address
#define OLED_ADDR   0x3C
// reset pin not used on 4-pin OLED module
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(-1);  // -1 = no reset pin
// 128 x 64 pixel display
#if (SSD1306_LCDHEIGHT != 64)
#error("Height incorrect, please fix Adafruit_SSD1306.h!");
#endif
#define DHTPIN D3
#define DHTTYPE DHT22
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
void setup() {

Serial.begin(115200);
delay(100);
  dht.begin();
  pinMode (DHTPIN, OUTPUT);
  /// initialize and clear display
  display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, OLED_ADDR);
  display.clearDisplay();
  //  display.drawRect(1, 1, display.width()-1, display.height()-1, WHITE);   // draws the outer rectangular boundary on the screen
  display.display();
  // display a pixel in each corner of the screen
  display.drawPixel(0, 0, WHITE);
  display.drawPixel(127, 0, WHITE);
  display.drawPixel(0, 63, WHITE);
  display.drawPixel(127, 63, WHITE);
  // display a line of text
  display.setTextSize(2);
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);
  display.setCursor(20, 18);
  display.print("Welcome");
  display.setCursor(25, 40);
  display.print("San");

  // update display with all of the above graphics
  display.display();
}
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  float h = dht.readHumidity();
  float t = dht.readTemperature();
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setTextSize(1);
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);
  display.setCursor(0, 1);
  display.print("Showing Temperature");
  // display Temperature
  display.setTextSize(2);
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);
  display.setCursor(1, 18);
  display.print("T : ");
  display.print(t);
  display.setTextSize(1);
  display.print((char)247);
  display.setTextSize(2);
  display.print("C");
  display.setCursor(1, 40);
  display.print("H : ");
  display.print(h);
  display.print(" %");
  // update display with all of the above graphics
  display.display();
}
```

After uploading code it does will display NaN but when I open serial monitor it works fine displaying actual values from DHT22  :o

below is the fritzing of the hookup, I do not have witty cloud in fritzing, so I have used wemos D1Mini instead. on wemos d1 mini 3v3 is VCC on witty cloud dev board.

[image]

It looks like loop function doesn't execute by itself unless I open the serial monitor, why is it so? please help

Comment: What happens if you remove/comment out "Serial.begin(115200);"?

Comment: Please show your wiring schematic. Do you use pull-up resistors for RX and TX?

Comment: Also asked at: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=512284 If you're going to do that then please be considerate enough to add links to the other places you cross posted. This will let us avoid wasting time due to duplicate effort and also help others who have the same questions and find your post to discover all the relevant information.

Comment: if i do not have serial monitor open loop function doesnt work. if I have serial monitor open the OLED updates, if i close serial monitor window the text on doest updates from the loop function.

why is loop function  dependent on serial monitor window being open ?

Comment: @MikaelPatel I have tried commenting that too didnt help, long time back I had similar issue and commented the serial.begin and it worked but with witty cloud dev board it didnt.

Comment: @AltAir I have added fritzing. please have a look

Comment: @per1234 I tried and troubleshooted to fix the issue but couldn't before posting on SO or arduino forum, I wanted to get the message to larger community so I can get some help.

Comment: The missing connection between GND of the D1 mini and breadboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell from your fritzing which actual ESP8266 pin you are using, but you require a pull up resistor on the data line of the DHT22.

My guess is that you are using one of the serial UART pins for the data connection, and opening the serial monitor activates the output of the onboard UART chip which then acts as your missing pullup resistor.

Comment: Used D7 i.e. GPIO13 on witty cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Serial monitor sends a RESET signal during its initialization - maybe this is the problem. Sometimes these Witty boards need an implicit RESET after power up / programming.